# Make Table Header Sticky relative to a certain component

Tags: css, sticky

**[Reproduction Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-paper-5ifbe?file=/index.html)**

I have an overall structure as shown below:
[image]

As you can see, it's scrollable. What I intend to do is allow scrolling until the table header like this:

[image]

Now scrolling beyond should fix the table header to the top and only let the body of the table move... I am unable to write CSS for the same. Note that I don't want the only the table to be scrollable. I want the whole container to be scrollable and once it reaches the table head then it should freeze to the top after which only the body should be scroll-friendly.

**My code:**

```css
.WholeContainer {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.miniWholeContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Filter {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.trhead {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fixing a certain Component within Scroll</h1>
<div class="WholeContainer">
  <div class="miniWholeContainer">
    <h1 class="Filter">Filter</h1>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>
        <tr class="trhead">
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
        </tr>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>E1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Reproduction Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-paper-5ifbe?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sticky position](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

With your example:

```css
.WholeContainer {
  height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.miniWholeContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Filter {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.trhead {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
.trhead {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fixing a certain Component within Scroll</h1>
    <div class="WholeContainer">
      <div class="miniWholeContainer">
        <h1 class="Filter">Filter</h1>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>
            <tr class="trhead">
              <td>A</td>
              <td>B</td>
              <td>C</td>
              <td>D</td>
              <td>E</td>
            </tr>
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>E1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm the answer you shared doesn't make head sticky.

Comment: It does. notice you  have 2 scroll bars if you just click on "run code snippet". better click on "expand snippet" to check it in a whole window.

Answer (score 0):

Show this example [Position Sticky and Table Headers](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

Comment: I already tried using this, but it didn't work in my case. Can you try and see with the sandbox link I have shared, to check if it works out there?